# LocalDateTime format with time zone and milliseconds

Tags: java, timezone, localdatetime

I'm trying to write a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the following format:

```
2020-05-29T07:51:33.106-07:00
```

I have looked at [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), but the problem is it does not contain milliseconds. So I decided to write on my own.

It is easy to do so without timezone:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    System.out.println(
        LocalDateTime.parse("2020-05-29T07:51:33.106", formatter)
    );
}
```

[It works just fine](https://ideone.com/H0htNS)

But when I tried to add a timezone in the format as

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    System.out.println(
        LocalDateTime.parse("2020-05-29T07:51:33.106-07:00", formatter)
    );
}
```

[It now fails with an exception](https://ideone.com/MKSfvS) that the timezone is unable to be parsed.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-05-29T07:51:33.106-07:00' could not be parsed at index 23
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1951)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:16)
```

How to parse a timezone in such a format?

Comment: FYI, `-07:00` is an offset-from-UTC ( `ZoneOffset` class), not a time zone (`ZoneId` class). A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

Comment: Correction: `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME,` parses milliseconds just fine. You need no other formatter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Javadoc (emphasis mine):

> **Offset Z:** This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the offset is zero. Four letters outputs the full form of localized offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero. *Five letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero, with colon. It outputs 'Z' if the offset is zero.* Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException.

Change the single `Z` to `ZZZZZ`.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

No need to define a formatter.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2020-05-29T07:51:33.106-07:00" )
```

## Details

The [Answer by Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62119071/642706) is correct. In addition, you are using the wrong class.

The `LocalDateTime` class represents only a date with a time-of-day, nothing more. This class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, this class cannot represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline.

[image]

So, parsing a string with an offset, the `-07:00` on the end, as a `LocalDateTime` does not make sense. The valuable information of offset will be ignored, discarded.

Instead, parse as an `OffsetDateTime`.

Bonus: Your entire formatter issue becomes moot. Your input string complies with the standard ISO 8601 format used by default in the `OffsetDateTime` class when parsing/generating strings. No need for you to define any custom formatting pattern at all.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2020-05-29T07:51:33.106-07:00" )
```

…and:

```
myOffsetDateTime.toString()
```

You said:

> But when I tried to add a timezone

No, you added an offset-from-UTC, not a time zone, with your string `-07:00`.

- An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian.
- A time zone is much more. A time zone has a name such as
  `America/Edmonton`. A time zone has a history of the past, present,
  and future changes to the offset in the wall-clock time used by the
  people of a particular region.